# Convert Excel (.xlsx) to HTML with Apache (Tika or POI) INCLUDING embedded objects (images, charts)

Tags: java, html, excel, apache-poi, apache-tika

I'm working to convert the content of an excel (*.xlsx*) file to html, to the best extent possible...

I tried both **Apache Tika** and directly **Apache POI**, but I haven't been able to extract charts or images included in an excel file. I also looked in the `XSSFExcelExtractorDecorator` class from the Apache Tika sources, but I don't understand how I should use that Decorator class, and I can't find an end-to-end example about this.

Can anybody provide a working example, or a hint for the starting point ?

Thank you.

Comment: refer: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tika/tika_extracting_ms_office_files.htm

Comment: I Was able to get up to this point, but that example only extracts text; it ignores images and charts, and that's where I'm stuck...

Comment: check: http://java.worldbestlearningcenter.com/2013/07/extract-images-from-word.html . Try similarly for excel

Comment: THAT (extracting images from a word doc or docx) I was also able to do :)

However, same process does not work also for excel files (I tried that as well) ...